Create a code which stops compilation when there are two equal labels
I would like to create a LaTeX code that stops compilation when there are two equal labels: in fact, the presence of two equal labels (at least using Texstudio) is only signalled by a simple warning. So, can anyone help me?

this is easy to do, but if you are writing a package and you plan to share that package, you shouldn't do it.

@cfr I am writing a package for my self.

well, that's different, of course. but if it were me, I would add prominent warnings when loading the package to remind myself I did this. (and maybe provide an option to turn it off.)

This will produce an error on the second compilation:
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{% mod from kernel
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    \relax
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
     \@latex@error{Label `#2' multiply defined}{}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}}

Note that some packages redefine \label. You provided no code, so I've assumed the default definitions.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{% mod from kernel
    \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    \relax
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
      \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
    \@latex@error{Label `#2' multiply defined}{}}%
\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{a}\label{a}
\section{b}\label{a}
\end{document}


Perfect: it seems your code works even with equations and lists! I upvoted your answer: before to approve let me some time (until tomorrow morning) to test better the code.

@AntonioMariaDiMauro well, it is redefining the macro responsible for creating labels and that means everything which uses that mechanism. so, yes, it should work generally, provided you're not loading packages which redefine \label etc. (even then, it may happen to work - it depends on how the redefinition is done.)
